# Most effiicient way to fill a 2D array with unique values?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to fill a 2D array (7 x 5) with unique integers. I've come up with two solutions: making a formula that guarantees a unique value using the indices of the 2D array (essentially a formula with `x` and `y` that always returns a unique value for `x` belonging to integers between 0 and 6 and `y` belonging to integers between 0 and 4); or using a method that checks if the value is unique to determine if I can store a given number in the array. I've created a method to use for the second option:

```
public static boolean isUnique(int num, int[][] intArray) {
    boolean isUnique = true;

    for (int x = 0; x < intArray.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < intArray[x].length; y++) {
            if (num == intArray[x][y]) {
                isUnique = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return isUnique;
}
```

I'm just wondering if this is one of the more optimal ways to do this or if anyone has any other suggestions. Am I just way overthinking this? I'm not too great at math, so I haven't been able to come up with a good way to do my first proposed solution.

Comment: Do you need *any* unique numbers? If so, just use consecutive integers.

Comment: Do you want unique and **random** values? Or just unique?

Comment: @PM77-1, that's exactly what I needed; I don't know how I start overthinking these things. Thanks!